# geom_hline ignoring colour aes for some reason

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom, geom-hline

```r
    line_data <- data.frame(value = c(1,2), color = as.factor(c("blue", "green"))
      plot1 <- plot1 +
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value, colour = color), line_data, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5)
```

The above is a snippet of my code. No matter what I assign to `color` column, it will be ignored. I can assign integers or continuous numbers. it will be ignored.

EDITED:

The reason is because `plot1` already has a `scale_color_manual` added to it. Now the challenge becomes how to make it work without having to remove the `scale_color_manual`?

Comment: Have a look at the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales for the same aesthetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post reproducible code to help us answer your question. We don't know what `plot1` is.

Use `scale_colour_identity` to tell ggplot2 to interpret the variable directly as a color:

```
line_data <- data.frame(value = c(1,2), color = as.factor(c("blue", "green")))
ggplot(line_data) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value, colour = color), line_data, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To make a new color legend compatible with an existing one, re-specify `scale_colour_manual`. You will still get the warning `Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.`, but it works:

```
library(ggplot2)

# example plot1 with manual scale
plot1data = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),
                       y=c(1,2,3,4),
                       color=factor(c(1,1,1,2)))
plot1 = ggplot(plot1data, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('1'='green','2'='red'))

# data you want to add to the plot
line_data <- data.frame(value = c(1,2), color = as.factor(c("blue", "green")))

# assume you have the plot1 object but no access to the code that generated it
# extract colors from plot1
ggdata = ggplot_build(plot1)$data[[1]]
plot1_colours = ggdata$colour
names(plot1_colours) = ggdata$group

# use the values originally specified for plot1 (plot_colours); add additional custom values  
plot1 + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value, colour = color), data = line_data, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(plot1_colours, 'blue'='blue', 'green'='green'))
```

[image]
Specify breaks if you want to remove some values from the legend:

```
plot1 + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value, colour = color), data = line_data, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(plot1_colours, 'blue'='blue', 'green'='green'), breaks = names(plot1_colours))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. It is because `plot1` already has a `scale_color_manual` added previously. How can I make it work without having to remove the current `scale_color_manual`?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages please see my updated answer